# Superpowered Library linking doesn't work

Tags: java, android, c++, audio, android-ndk

I try add superpowered library to new android studio project and I follow example for Android but I still have problems with linking library.

I have this error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.xxx.audiomixprototype.MainActivity.AudioMixPrototype(java.lang.String, long[]) (tried Java_com_xxx_audiomixprototype_MainActivity_AudioMixPrototype and Java_com_xxx_audiomixprototype_MainActivity_AudioMixPrototype__Ljava_lang_String_2_3J)

I follow short tutorial from Superpowered github readme 
https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine

and everything is clear but I don't understand last point:

> create your custom .cpp and .h files, then donÕt forget to properly set LOCAL_MODULE and LOCAL_SRC_FILES in Android.mk

Probably this is the reason why I can't link correctly this library. Any solutions how properly set LOCAL_MODULE and LOCAL_SRC_FILES?

Comment: That error message looks incomplete; it should have given you the full method signature it was trying to match. Could you update the post with the full line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. When I copy SuperpoweredExample.cpp file I didn't change JNIEXPORT in this file.

I have this:

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_com_superpowered_crossexample_MainActivity_SuperpoweredExample(JNIEnv *javaEnvironment, jobject self, jstring apkPath, jlongArray offsetAndLength);
```

Instead this:

```
JNIEXPORT void Java_com_xxx_audiomixprototype_MainActivity_SuperpoweredExample(JNIEnv *javaEnvironment, jobject self, jstring apkPath, jlongArray offsetAndLength);
```

I know stupid mistake but maybe someone else will have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making some guesses here, so I'll outline my assumptions about your project.

1) You have a Java file with the line:

```
private native void AudioMixPrototype(String apkPath, long[] offsetAndLength);
```

2) You have a JNI implementation of this method in src/main/jni/filename.cpp

If you haven't set LOCAL_MODULE and LOCAL_SRC_FILES correctly in your Android.mk, Java won't be able to resolve the JNI call to this method, hence the link error. You'll need to add the following to your Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# name your JNI module
LOCAL_MODULE := audio-mix-prototype 

# assuming your Android.mk is also in src/main/jni, 
# provide the filename to the JNI implementation of your method
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := filename.cpp

# add your flags, other libraries, etc. here

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

There are some good examples in the Superpowered SDK. You can see an example of an Android.mk file for a project depending on Superpowered [here](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/blob/master/Android/CrossExample/app/src/main/jni/Android.mk).

Comment: Ok I make new project with the same code as example "Cross Example" and I still have this problem. 
My Android.mk file is the same, I only change path to the Superpowered.

Comment: My Android.mk file is the same, I only change path to the Superpowered and in LOCAL_SRC_FILES I add direct paths to the  SuperpoweredExample.cpp and SuperpoweredAndroidAudioIO.cpp

Comment: How are you loading your native library from Java?

Comment: What do you mean? I use Java code code from Cross example.

Comment: Can you clarify what parts of your project are different from the example? It's unclear to me if you are using the example code with some modifications, or if you have copied parts of the example into a different project. If you used the Java code from the example in a different project, you would need to modify it in several places for it to work.

Comment: I'm not going to dig through your code dump. Sorry, but if you're not even willing to explain how you're setting up your project, I can't help. Good luck figuring it out.